# Code Editor for Android that supports a "jump to definition" feature

Tags: android, c++, code-analysis

I want to browse a cpp project with 400+ files on my phone. The app in question must have a "jump to definition" feature, that works across project files. All the cpp/h files are in a single folder.

So far I have found this, but it seems complicated:
https://raymii.org/s/blog/Run_CLion_on_Android.html

These don't support "got to definition":

- [Code Studio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alif.ide&hl=en&gl=US)
- [Cxxdroid - C/C++ compiler IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.cxxdroid&hl=en&gl=US)